# how to get while loop data from multiple looping

Tags: php, database, loops

**I can not get rules point data from while loop. Please help me.... :(**

Below is my code

```
<?php 
                                    $employee_query = $dbcon->query("SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY name ASC");
                                    while($employee_array = $employee_query->fetch_array()):
                                    $employee_ids = $employee_array['id'];
                                    $department_ids = $employee_array['department_id'];

                                    $department_query = $dbcon->query("SELECT * FROM department WHERE id='$department_ids'");
                                    $department_array = $department_query->fetch_assoc();
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> <small> <strong> <?= $employee_array['name']; ?> </strong> </small> </td>
                                    <td> <small> <strong> <?= $department_array['department']; ?> </strong> </small> </td>
                                    <td> <small> <strong> <?= $y; ?> </strong> </small> </td>
                                    <td> <small> <strong> <?= $m; ?> </strong> </small> </td>
                                    <td> <small> <strong> <?= $w; ?> Week </strong> </small> </td>
                                    <td> <small> <strong> <?= $pd['week_range']; ?> </strong> </small> </td>
                                    <td>
                                    <?php 
                                        $pm_query = $dbcon->query("SELECT * FROM performance_management WHERE performance_id='$pid' AND department_id='$department_ids' AND employee_id='$employee_ids'");
                                        while($pm_data = $pm_query->fetch_array()):
                                            echo $rules_ids = $pm_data['rules_id'];

                                            $rules_query = $dbcon->query("SELECT * FROM point WHERE rules_id='$rules_ids'");
                                            $rules_data = $rules_query->fetch_assoc();

                                            echo $rules_data['points'];
                                        endwhile;
                                    ?>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
```

In above code, I can not get `$rules_data['points']`

Comment: `fetch_assoc` return the `associative array` . so access it like this `echo $rules_data[0]['points'];`

Comment: I get "$rules_ids" value but this value can not use at "$rules_query"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch_assoc()` returns all the `row` as `associative array` . so access it like this

`echo $rules_data[0]['points'];`

**Update :**

your `$rules_ids` values are `47,30,36` so you need to use `IN clause` query

```
"SELECT * FROM point WHERE rules_id IN (".$rules_ids.")"
```

Comment: what you have inside the `$rules_ids` give some sample data @AungHtetPaing

Comment: I got "$rules_ids" values as "47,30,36" from database. I want to use this values at "$rules_query". but I get some data when query string does not use "WHERE" statement.

Comment: you need to use `in` clause query  `"SELECT * FROM point WHERE rules_id IN (".$rules_ids.")"`

Comment: Thank I got it... :)  JYoThl